# Flynt Theme : How to stop to add random number suffix to assets filenames such as css, js and images

Tags: wordpress, webpack, wordpress-theming

I love the Flynt theme. very perfect!!!.
but I have a trouble. I am not expert for webpack.

so when I am run `npm run build`, images files have the random suffix after this action.
for example, `flynt\assets\images\facebook.svg` will do like `flynt\dist\assets\images\facebook-9f900a2130.svg`

but I made the css like the following

```
.facebook {
    background-image: url('../assets/images/facebook.svg');
 }
```

as you see, after `npm run build` , site can't find the original `facebook.svg` file

what is the best way to fix my trouble

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solutions.

I commented rev function in gulpfile.js.

```
function rev () {
  gulp.task('rev', gulp.series([
    // 1) Add md5 hashes to assets referenced by CSS and JS files
    'revAssets',
    // 2) Update asset references (images, fonts, etc) with reved filenames in compiled css + js
    'revUpdateReferences',
    // 3) Rev and compress CSS and JS files (this is done after assets, so that if a referenced asset hash changes, the parent hash will change as well
    'revRevvedFiles',
    // 4) Update asset references in HTML
    'revStaticFiles'
  ]))
}
```

so the compiled files never have hash string.